# MediaPlayer play audio in background and play next one

Tags: android, media-player

I use below code to play audio in background:

```
String[] Path = new String[] {path1, path2, ...};
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Path[i]);
mMediaPlayer.prepare();
mMediaPlayer.start();
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
```

While I play the first one Path[0] in background.
I want to make it auto play next one Path[1] after Path[0] play finish, how to arrive it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should override onCompletionListener like this,

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {           
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {          
        Log.i("Completion Listener","Song Complete");
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource([nextElement]);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

If you use a onPreparedListener in your MediaPlayer then you cal also use the prepareAsync command and ignore the .start().

Comment: Another error "java.lang.IllegalStateException" and "at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)".

Comment: I think you shud remove release() and try reset() instead. am sorry. its been days since I used these.

Comment: @AndroSelva is correct that it is reset(). Answer updated to mirror that change.

Comment: This is the proper way of completing your video :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You need to set an OnCompletionListener to your MediaPlayer, in the listener set the source to path2, prepare and play.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html