# Media Player memory management in Android?

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, media-player

I am newbie in Android.
I have problem in understanding MediaPlayer memory management in android.
I am declaring all MediaPlayer objects globally & creating it in onCreate() & starts it when i need it & releases it immediately after completion.I create them again when i need it. Is this a good way ?
Should i create them in a method where i need it or creating it in onCreate is fine ?
But if i create them in onCreate(), than i can't release them.
Is there any alternative way to release() function of MediaPlayer to free the garbage memory ?

```
MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2......mpn;
@override
protected void onCreate(){
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext() , R.raw.sound);
//same for all objects.creating here will require more memory ? 
}
```

now,method

```
private void method(){
mp.start();
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
            mp= null;
        }
    });
}
//same for all objects when i need them.
```

where should i declare, create and initialize them for a good memory management, as i am using lots of MediaPlayer objects.?

Comment: reuse the same you can reset your mediaplayer by calling `mp.reset()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: will reset() free the memory like release() ?

Comment: Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. After calling this method, you will have to initialize it again by setting the data source and calling prepare(). for release check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223745/mediaplayer-play-audio-in-background-and-play-next-one. if it helps. `onCreate` is called once during the lifecycle unless activtiy is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Is there any benefit or loss for using reset() ?

Comment: pls check the docs for more info

Comment: Thank you very much.But i have already read docs but can't understand.So, i decided to post here.

Answer (score 3):

Memory is not the issue here. Your MediaPlayer is a small proxy object, you can keep it, or delete, it doesn't really matter. What does matter is that you should call release() as soon as possible because otherwise the real player (low-level service) may continue to hold codec instances and internal buffers, and on some devices may even keep unnecessary pieces of hardware powered on.

Comment: to play next song op will have to create meadiplayer object again.

Comment: Is there any benefit or loss for using reset() ?

Comment: you will not be creating a new media player object everytime and you will be resuing the same media player object. when you are done with mediaplayer then you can release the same like in `onPause` or `onStop` of your activity

Comment: if you want to start playing new file and you are using recent API (16+), you can use setNextMediaPlayer instead. If you are not going to start new playback right away, I don't see much use in reset() - you can always create a new instance of the player when you need it

Comment: @Raghunandan how can i use my sound from raw folder after using reset() ?

Comment: @user2797658 `public static Uri getUriFromId(Context context, @RawRes int resId) {
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + resId);
    }`

Comment: @msh hi i am using media player for live stream when to release the mediaplayer?