# Android background music service restart

Tags: java, android, service

My application control music in class extents application using service. Background music service called when application starts. And Overriding onUserLeaveHint() to stop service.

To prevent music stop across activities, I added flag

```
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
```

So Music isn't stopped and it works fine.
**But problem is home button.**

When I push home button, music stopped. And then I open application music still stopped. Because there are no call for start service, only except application onCreate.

That's why I want to restart service. 
**How can I check service started or stopped?**

Thanks for read this question!

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947867/android-music-player-service-not-playing-after-home-back-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start the service on onResume or on onStart method.